# VueJS playing audio inside a component

Tags: html, html5-audio

This is my use case.
I want to play a sound clip (clock ticking sound) continuesly in my vue component. I do it in normal html way but it doesn't work here and even not gives an error in the console. I want to play this sound continuesly in the component. How do I achieve this?

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <audio controls id="myVideo" autoplay loop Pause=false hidden>

    <source src="clock-ticking-2.wav" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
  <h1>Hello I'm clock ticking!</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure you can reach .wav file? Even if you reach, is it really a wav file or some html?

Comment: I didn't get anything as an error.

Comment: That is why I'm confused.